# how can spirts/sould see physical things without eyes

Tags: mind

I was listening and watching the [Tibetan Book of the Dead (Audiobook)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1MZwriqVvw) and i got one question in my mind. When soul/conciousness leaves physical body how can it see all the physical things without a physical eyes?

Comment: Why does it need to see physical things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the eye faculty to see. In Humans and animals you have a physical eye made of gross material. In finer material spheres you will have eyes with finer material. Only in immaterial realms you will be without sense faculties.

In finer material realm your sense faculties are finer / shapere than being gross faculties. This is why in [super normal powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhij%C3%B1%C4%81) this one of the power is know are [divine [godly/heavenly]](https://suttacentral.net/define/dibba) eye.

In all realms you have the 6 faculties in some for or the other except in the immaterial realms where you do not have the physical faculties.

Being in some finer material realm (heavens and hells) can see people in our realm and perhaps other realms also.

Perhaps in other realms also there might be being without an eye faculty like the blind in our realm. I don't this there being would be able to see.